# Error in Batch file when 2nd parameter is not supplied

Tags: batch-file

Here is a batch file, I need to set the second parameter to a certain path if it is not supplied, else use the value of second parameter further. Note that i need to access the value of EXECUTE_DIR, further in the file

dummy.bat

```
IF %2 == "" (
SET EXECUTE_DIR = "c:\Program Files"
) ELSE (
SET EXECUTE_DIR = %2
)

ECHO exedir = %EXECUTE_DIR%
```

-

when I provide only 1 parameter, I get following output:

D:>dummy.bat "Lab"

( was unexpected at this time.

D:>IF  == "" (

D:>

Answer (score 1):

you need

```
if "%2"=="" ....
```

both sides of the comparison operator must **exactly** match. If `%2` does not exist, your code is resolved to

```
if =="" ...
```

which is clearly a syntax error as reported.

My preferred version is

```
set "var=%~2"
if not defined var ...
```

which conveniently assigns the value of `%2`, with enclosing quotes removed, to `var`.

naturally, you could use `if defined var...` if that's more convenient.

meanwhile, your `)else(` will also generate an error. You must have spaces both sides of the `else`, otherwise `cmd` doesn't know whether you are invoking an `else` clause or `)else(` is some variety of variable or option or whatever.

The `)` and `(` must also be on the same physical line as the `else` keyword (which you have).

(belay that - proportional-space ib unformatted text makes the spaces hard to spot...)

But that brings up another point - Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N". The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`.